# jQuery slide panel back up

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a panel which contains a responsive carousel so I need to preserve the height of the container which means I can't use

```
display:none
```

So I have preserved the height and am positioning it off the top out of sight, when the user clicks a button it slides down.

I just need to allow the user to click the button again and have it slide up.

Here is what I have:

```
$('a.myCourses').on('click', function() {
  $('#courseCart').animate({'top': '0'}, 1000);
  $(this).addClass('open');
});
```

This slides the panel down. I added a class thinking I could target the button again and have it slide up but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include a switch to check if your carousell is already open, then you can slide it up again. 
See her in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gbzhhc5d/3/

```
$('a.myCourses').on('click', function() {
if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    $('#courseCart').animate({'top': '-100'}, 1000);
    $(this).removeClass('open');
}
else {
    $('#courseCart').animate({'top': '0'}, 1000);
    $(this).addClass('open');
}

});
```

Comment: thanks Kalle, looks so simple to complete this task when you show the function like that.